# JS Change text onClick then change back onClick If...else

Tags: javascript, text, onclick

Here's an easy one.

I'm creating a link with content that changes onClick. Onload it should say ""Click here for more information!" when clicked, it should say "Click here for less information!" then on re-click "...more information".

I'm sure that I'm just making a tiny mistake somewhere, help?

JavaScript

```
<script>
function change_text()
{
if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for more   
information!"){
document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for less
information!";
}else{
    document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for more     
information!";
}}
</script>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<a href='javascript: toggle()'><p id="toggle_button" onclick="change_text()">Click here  
for more information!</p></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only are you misusing `=` as `===`, but you can also greatly improve your code with a simple technique: caching.

```
function change_text() {
    var button = document.getElementById('toggle_button');

    if (button.innerHTML === "Click here for more information!") {
        button.innerHTML = "Click here for less information!";
    }
    else {
        button.innerHTML = "Click here for more information!";
    }
}
```

You can see how way clearer the code becomes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's very much appreciated and works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for more   
information!"){
```

should be

```
if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML == "Click here for more   
information!"){
```

you are assigning rather than comparing, so use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Thank you for having responded. It's very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

use this for your problem it will help you better-

1. check equal use  '=='
2. javascript:void(0) use on href

   ```
           <html>
             <head>

               <title>index</title>

             </head>
             <body>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                   function change_text()
                       {
                           if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML=="Click here for more information!")
                           {
                               document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for less information!";
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for more information!";
                           }
                       }
           </script>
            <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="change_text()"><p id="toggle_button" >Click here for more information!</p></a>  

             </body>
           </html>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for having responded. It's very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have miss "=" in

```
 if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for more   
    information!")
```

Try this code:

```
<script>
function change_text()
{
if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML=="Click here for more   
information!"){
document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for less
information!";
}else{
    document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Click here for more     
information!";
}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for having responded. It's very much appreciated!